# php 8.1 access Microsoft SQL Server 2019 with freetds

Tags: php, pdo, apt, sql-server-2019, ubuntu-22.04

What packages are needed to use pdo to connect to mssql-server 2019 through freetds

I want to use php's pdo to access Microsoft's SQL-Server 2019 under ubuntu 22.04. Is it possible to use freetds? In addition to php, php-cli, php-common, I only need to install freetds. I don’t need to install php-odbc or any other packages, right?

I originally installed php-sqlsrv, but I didn’t know how to fix it, and it always showed cloud not find driver. Then I removed it and installed it through other methods. In the end, my package library was completely broken. Even after reinstalling php, files such as php.ini would not appear. So I dare not try again.